# Doctrine2 Join count on same table returning empty array

Tags: symfony, join, doctrine-orm, inner-join, query-builder

```
$messageQuery
            ->select('m, COUNT(pm) AS newResponses')
            //->addSelect($messageQuery->expr()->countDistinct('pm.id'))
            ->from('entities:PrivateMessage', 'm')
            ->where('m.employeeId = :employeeId AND m.responseTo = 0')
            ->innerJoin('entity:PrivateMessage', 'pm', 'WITH', 'pm.responseTo = m.id AND pm.employeeRead = 0')
            ->setParameter('employeeId', $employeeId)
            ->setFirstResult($offset)
            ->setMaxResults($max)
            ->addGroupBy('m.id')
            ->orderBy('m.id', 'DESC');
```

Let's assume there are two messages with employeeId = 1 and responseTo = 0. One of those messages also has two responses (therefore two other records with responseTo = messageId). The other has none. The result I would expect from this query is two arrays with the entity object as index 0, and the count as index numResponses (value of 2 for the first row, 0 for the second). What I'm getting back is an empty array on $messageQuery->getQuery()->getResult();

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this may be happening? Is there something obvious I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I seem to have fixed it by switching to a leftJoin.